# Hunting for the 100,001st prime in Rust

Tags: python, rust, primes, library

Most of my programming experience is in **Python**, but my first language was **C**, and I was intrigued by the combination which **Rust** offers: a streamlined syntax and no manual memory management, but with all the performance possibilities that a strongly typed, low-level language has to offer.

To that end, I have begun teaching myself Rust. I have tried bits of Rust code to solve some well-understood mathematical problems, and my code managed to spit out the right answers. So now I am posting some of that code to double check that I am not doing anything  egregiously daft from a performance or stylistic point of view.

I am posting two code files, both of which find the 100,001st prime number, and print it to the screen. Why two files? One uses a function which I wrote myself to determine whether a given number is prime; the other uses a library function.

The code with the custom function:

```rust
/// My attempt at Project Euler Problem 7, in Rust (obv).

// Local constants.
const TARGET_PRIME_COUNT: i32 = 100001;

/// Determine whether a given number is prime.
fn is_prime(num: i32) -> bool {
    if num == 1 {
        return false;
    }
    if num == 2 {
        return true;
    }
    if num%2 == 0 {
        return false;
    }

    let terminus = ((num as f64).sqrt().ceil() as i32)+1;

    for i in 3..terminus {
        if num%i == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}

// Find the nth prime number.
fn find_nth_prime(n: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut current = 0;

    while count < n {
        current += 1;

        if is_prime(current) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return current;
}

/// This is where the magic happens.
fn main() {
    let solution: i32 = find_nth_prime(TARGET_PRIME_COUNT);
    println!("{}", solution);
}
```

The code using the library function:

```rust
/// My attempt at Project Euler Problem 7, in Rust (obv).
/// The twist is that this time I'm using a library for is_prime().

// Standard imports.
use primes;

// Local constants.
const TARGET_PRIME_COUNT: i32 = 100001;

// Find the nth prime number.
fn find_nth_prime(n: i32) -> i32 {
    let mut count = 0;
    let mut current = 0;

    while count < n {
        current += 1;

        if primes::is_prime(current) {
            count += 1;
        }
    }

    return current as i32;
}

/// This is where the magic happens.
fn main() {
    let solution = find_nth_prime(TARGET_PRIME_COUNT);
    println!("{}", solution);
}
```

#### Performance Notes

For an idea of the step-up in performance I might get from using Rust, I repeated this exercise in Python, and timed how long each took to run. These are the results:

- Python, with custom function: 4.444s.
- Python, with library function: 1.832s.

Now here are the results for Rust:

- Rust, with custom function: 1.472s.
- Rust, with library function: 2.116s.

I have to say, I am surprised by a couple of things:

1. How close the two languages are in terms of speed on this specific test. Sure, the differences would begin to stack up if we were repeating this process millions of times, but it's not an order of magnitude kind of difference. And, using libraries, Python is actually faster than Rust. How mad is that!
2. That the Rust library function is actually slower than my custom function.

I get that, regarding Python's relative speed, the Python library is almost certainly calling some non-Python code to do the heavy lifting. But, even so, the above seems a bit fishy to me. Am I making some small but very silly mistake in my Rust code which is artificially slowing it down?

---

For anyone interested in the impressively performing Python code, this is it:

````
import sympy

TARGET_PRIME_COUNT = 100001

def run():
    current = 0
    prime_count = 0
    while prime_count < TARGET_PRIME_COUNT:
        current += 1
        if sympy.isprime(current):
            prime_count += 1
    print(current)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    run()
```
````

Comment: _Have you compiled with `--release`?_

Comment: What is the Python code?

Comment: I don’t know Rust, but in C++ you can easily get a 100x speed difference between debug and optimized builds.

Comment: @ChayimRefaelFriedman Just tried compiling it with `--release`. (Thanks for the tip.) Didn't make any appreciable difference in timings.

Comment: @ChayimRefaelFriedman Added the Python library-using code to the end of my question.

Comment: @TomHosker After compiling with `--release`, the optimized executable will be at `target/release/<crate_name>`, and you can measure execution time with `time ./target/release/<crate_name>`. If you're doing `time cargo run`, it is using the unoptimized executable at `target/debug/<crate_name>`.

Comment: for reference, here are the results of running your code snippets on my machine (note: I added one more snippet for comparison that uses the `primal` crate), using `500001` for `TARGET_PRIME_COUNT` instead of `100001` to show the differences more clearly. `Python (sympy version 1.12): 5.26s`, `Rust (custom): 0.76s`, `Rust (primes version 0.3.0): 0.53s`, `Rust (primal version 0.3.2): 0.36s`

Answer (score 1):

We want speed!

```
    if num%2 == 0 {
        return false;
    }
```

That is certainly nice, and efficient;
it dovetails nicely with the `3..` loop.
Consider hardcoding the first few elements of a sieve,
so only a smallish fraction of candidates
go through the exhaustive testing loop.

```
    for i in 3..terminus {
        if num%i == 0 {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

Consider storing all found primes and sieving through them,
so the loop uses a cheap multiply
instead of the slightly expensive div / modulo operation.

---

```
        current += 1;
```

You have an opportunity to `+= 2`,
making fewer function calls,
if you like.

---

Switching over to python now...

```
TARGET_PRIME_COUNT = 100001
```

Please spell that

```
TARGET_PRIME_COUNT = 100_001
```

Also, same remark about opportunity for `current += 2`.

---

```
        if sympy.isprime(current):
```

Sooo, nominally this is "python" code. But
[profiling](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html#module-cProfile)
will reveal that all the time got sucked up within that function call.

---

Consider letting
[numba](https://pypi.org/project/numba)
JIT that driver loop for you.